# Cant figure out how to create multiple Modelforms with different prefix django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am working on a specific view on a project and I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish it.

I want to dynamically duplicate a single form in a Django view and for each of the forms, add a prefix to each of the forms based on a data field from a query set. I want to then pass in the duplicate forms into the HTML where the user can input information in the fields and then submit it.

The issue is that I can't figure out how to create duplicate forms with different prefixes based on the results of a query set. and assign each prefix to the username of the user record that is being called.

So lets say I have a query set that calls a query set to pull all of the users whose names start with t. and for every user in the users query, I want to create a form based on the inividualsplitform and for each of the forms, add the prefix with the username that is attached to the specific user. And I want to pass each of the forms to the HTML template and display the forms in the HTML file. Once the user fills out the forms, I want to be able to go through the same query and form every user in the user's query, use the username as an eay to identify each of the different forms and extract the information.

What happens right now is that it creates one form for the last user in the user's query and pushes that form and only that form rather than all of the forms. and only the last one is coming back to be processed by the view.

Here is the view that I have right now:

```
def addTransaction(request, groupId, recordId):
    user = User.objects.get(username='omar')
    group = Group.objects.get(id=groupId)
    record = Record.objects.get(id=recordId)
    transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(record=recordId).all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if record.split == 1:
            form = EvenSplitTransactionForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                cd = form.cleaned_data
                amount = cd['amount']
                description = cd['description']
                split_amount = SplitEven(record, amount)
                for trans in transactions:
                    if trans.record.id == record.id:
                        trans.description = description
                        trans.amount = split_amount
                        trans.save()
                return redirect('group_home', groupId=group.id)
        if record.split == 2:
            # this is where i want to iterate though the formset and get the info
            # that i need from the forms that the user submitted.
            forms = TransFormSet()
            for form in forms:
                display = 'message'
                print(display)
        return redirect('accounts')
    else:
        if record.split == 1:
            form = EvenSplitTransactionForm()
            message = 'fill out the form below'
            parameters = {
                'record':record,
                'form':form,
                'message':message,
                'transactions':transactions,
            }
            return render(request, 'tabs/add_even_transactions.html', parameters)
        if record.split == 2:
            for transaction in transactions:
                form = IndividualSplitTransactionForm(prefix = transaction.user.username)
            print(form)
            message = 'message'
            parameters = {
                'record':record,
                'form':form,
                'message':message,
                'transactions':transactions,
            }
            return render(request, 'tabs/add_individual_transaction.html', parameters)
```

Updated:
I got the forms to work but I am having issues with the form list validation and collection of the informaiton that was submitted with the form.

```
def addTransaction(request, groupId, recordId):
    user = User.objects.get(username='omar')
    group = Group.objects.get(id=groupId)
    record = Record.objects.get(id=recordId)
    transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(record=recordId).all().count()
    formset = formset_factory(IndividualSplitTransactionForm, extra=transactions)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if record.split == 1:
            form = EvenSplitTransactionForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                cd = form.cleaned_data
                amount = cd['amount']
                description = cd['description']
                split_amount = SplitEven(record, amount)
                for trans in transactions:
                    if trans.record.id == record.id:
                        trans.description = description
                        trans.amount = split_amount
                        trans.save()
                return redirect('group_home', groupId=group.id)
        if record.split == 2:
            cheese = 'cheese'
            # this is where i want to iterate though the formset and get the info
            # that i need from the forms that the user submitted.
            # form = formList(request.POST)
            # if form.is_valid():
            #     cd = form.cleaned_data
            #     for transaction in transactions:
            #         amount = transaction.user.username + '-amount'
            #         description = transaction.user.username + '-description'
            #         currentAmount = cd[amount]
            #         currentDescription = cd[description]
            #         transaction.amount = currentAmount
            #         transaction.description = currentDescription
            #         transaction.save()
            #     return redirect('group_home', groupId=group.id)
        return redirect('accounts')
    else:
        if record.split == 1:
            form = EvenSplitTransactionForm()
            message = 'fill out the form below'
            parameters = {
                'record':record,
                'form':form,
                'message':message,
                'transactions':transactions,
            }
            return render(request, 'tabs/add_even_transactions.html', parameters)
        if record.split == 2:
            print(formset)
            message = 'message'
            parameters = {
                'record':record,
                'formset':formset,
                'message':message,
                'transactions':transactions,
            }
            return render(request, 'tabs/add_individual_transaction.html', parameters)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing Label

```
from django.forms import BaseFormSet
class BaseTestFormset(BaseFormSet):
    def add_fields(self, form, index):
        super().add_fields(form, index)
        form.fields['your field name'].label = "new label"
        return form

TestFormset = formset_factory(TestForm, formset=BaseTestFormSet)
```

if you have username list, you can change "new label" as usernameList[index]

```
exList = ["hello", "there"]

...
def add_fields(self, form, index):
    super().add_fields(form, index)
    form.fields['your field name'].label = exList[index]
    return form
```

---

Using Formset

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    TestFormSet = formset_factory(TestForm)
    formset = TestFormSet(request.POST)
    if formset.is_valid():
        for form in formset:
             form.save()
    ...

else:
    TestFormSet = formset_factory(TestForm, extra=0)
    initial_list = []
    for transaction in transactions:
        initial_list.append({'username': transaction.user.username, 'anotherField': transaction.anotherField})
    formset = TestFormSet(initial=initial_list)
    ...
    return render(request, .. { .. , 'formList':formset})
```

---

If your problem is that it displays only last form, you need to look at this part of your code.

```
for transaction in transactions:
    form = IndividualSplitTransactionForm(prefix = transaction.user.username)
```

You save very last form in form variable. So I think you can consider like below.

```
formList = []
# make list object with form elements
for transaction in transactions:
    form = IndividualSplitTransactionForm()
    formList.append(form)
...

# send formList in Context
parameters = {
            'record':record,
            'formList':formList,
            'message':message,
            'transactions':transactions,
        }

# In your html, you can iterate your formList and show each form.
{% for form in formList %}
   {{form}}
{% endfor %}
```

---

Answer for additional questions

I understood that there is username field in form. So My suggestion is like this.

```
for transaction in transactions:
    form = IndividualSplitRansactionFrom(initial={'fieldname which has FK for user instance' : user})
```

My idea is that you put username value in form by setting initial value.

Comment: thank you so much. that worked, once question. is there a way to extract the prefix from the form within the html file and is there a way to extranct the prefix from the form label within the view when it is submitted

Comment: so that it can display the prefix/username above each of the forms so that the user knows which form belongs to which user. same with the view for processing

Comment: I have a different question. I am trying to process the form list and I cant exactly figure out how to go about that. I tried validating the form and grabbing cleaned data, but I dont think it is working. Can you look at the code in the updated part of the current question. if you can look at it and let me know if there is something i am missing of have to change because it is an array... @Jayground

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't explain how to save with those forms. Let's say you have three forms and each form has input like `<input type="text" name="username" />` for an example. Then, you will get list value with 'username' name. you can write `print(request.POST.getlist('username')` and check in your console. So my idea is that you iterate this list value and put attribute in each form and validate individually.

Comment: I will update my answer soon. I think I gave you a wrong answer. Using formset would be easier and right approach. [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/formsets/)

Comment: I tried formsets before i changed my code but i couldnt figure out how to check if the formset is valid so i just gave up on it and tried the way i have it now.

Comment: Is there a way to add a prefix or chage the label to an individual form in a formset... I changed the updated code to have the code that I used for the formset... @Jayground